# OrientDB SELECT and subqueries

Tags: orientdb

I'm really puzzled about this.
Why does this works:

```
SELECT out('Posted').out('IsFromCategory') FROM #18:1
```

And this does not:

```
SELECT out('IsFromCategory') FROM (SELECT out('Posted') FROM #18:1)
```

That's not me real logic, but is something I came up doing some tests...

Comment: I just realised I have to use "expand" in the subquery, but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you realised, you need to use `expand` in your subquery, so it would look like

```
SELECT out('IsFromCategory') FROM (SELECT expand(out('Posted')) FROM #18:1)
```

It's like the subquery without the `expand` returns a list of `@rid`, so there's nothing to select from there, while after expanding, you get a list with the whole entities (vertices) from which you can traverse any edge they have.

(Not sure why this behaves differently from your first query. Maybe, because the first is one query and you ask explicitly to traverse, whereas the second is two queries and when the subquery returns it doesn't know that you want the whole vertex retrieved).