# Orient DB creating edge between vertices error, vertices are reading by using Orient DB SQL functions

Tags: orientdb

I'm facing an issue to create edge between vertices, where one of the vertex is getting by using orient SQL function,

below is requirement

let say I have 3 vertices vertex1(@rid: #9:0), vertex2(@rid: #10:0), vertex3(@rid: #11:0), and edge beteween vertex1 and vertex 2 is already exist.
Now I need to get vertex1 from vertex2 and create edges between vertex1 and vertex3

```
Graph graph = new OrientGraph("remote:localhost:2424/test", "username", "password");
String query = "select @rid ad base, inE('child').outV() as source from V where name='vertex3'";

OrientGraph oGraph = (OrientGraph)graph;
OCommandSQL oCommandSQL = new OCommandSQL(query);
Iterable<Vertex> vertices = oGraph.command(oCommandSQL).execute();
Iterator<Vertex> verticesIterator = vertices.iterator();
Vertex resultVertex = verticesIterator.next();
OrientElementIterable<Element> elements = resultVertex.getProperty("source");
Iterator<Element> elementIterator = elements.iterator();
Vertex sourceVertex = null;
while (elementIterator.hasNext()) {
    sourceVertex = (Vertex) elementIterator.next();
}
Vertex v3 = graph.getVertex("#11:0");
Edge edge = graph.addEdge(null, v3, sourceVertex, "new");
graph.shutdown();
```

Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cluster segment #-2 does not exist
>   in database 'test'
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.checkClusterSegmentIndexRange(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:4627)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.getClusterById(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3013)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.readRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1404)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx$SimpleRecordReader.readRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:3411)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2022)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.loadRecord(OTransactionOptimistic.java:187)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.loadRecord(OTransactionOptimistic.java:162)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.loadRecord(OTransactionOptimistic.java:291)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.load(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1739)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.load(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:103)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId.getRecord(ORecordId.java:329)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.tx.OTransactionOptimisticProxy.begin(OTransactionOptimisticProxy.java:176)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.begin(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1881)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.begin(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:103)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.commit(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1426)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:668)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.sessionRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:398)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.execute(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:217)
>           at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:82)

Comment: Hi, which version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using orientdb-community-2.2.8

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got my code working with UNWIND function

```
String query = "select @rid ad base, inE('child').outV() as source from V where name='vertex3' UNWIND source";
```

we can also use EXPAND function

```
String query = "select @rid ad base, EXPAND(inE('child').outV()) as source from V where name='vertex3'";
```

But it will ignore multiple projections

Below links helped me to fix this

[OrientDB SELECT and subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167773/orientdb-select-and-subqueries)

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3755

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Query.html#unwinding

Thank you,